# How expensive is WearableListenerService? (Wear Os)

Tags: android, service, wear-os, memory-efficient

I am working on a new wear application with a companion mobile app.
It will rarely be necessary to transfer information from the mobile to the watch via Bluetooth connection.
The main wear app is standalone, so transferring data from the mobile phone is a luxury because it will be a more convenient way to set up user preferences than doing it on the watch (Although the settings menu will also exist on the watch).

So I have a dilemma between two options:

1. Listen to messages coming through the Bluetooth connection only when the app is open on the watch. 
   The **advantage** here is resource savings and efficiency (but the question is how much).
   The **disadvantage** is a lesser user experience.
2. Set up a `WearableListenerService` that will always listen to messages coming from the mobile phone.
   The **advantage** here is a high user experience since the user will not have to open the app on the watch in order to transfer the data.
   The **disadvantage** here is a waste of resources (and again the question of how much).

What should I do?
 How expensive is `WearableListenerService` in terms of system resources and battery life in particular?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'm not sure you should have to worry about the cost of WearableListenerService, when there isn't an event such as a message, or an update to the data. You can filter what you are interested in, so I wouldn't worry about it.  If it's expensive when not being used and drains the battery, then I would consider that a bug that should be fixed.

Comment: This is also what came to my mind when I thought about this issue because `onMessageReceived()` is only raised using a predefined `intent-filter`. Thank you very much for sharing your opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [`WearableListenerService` docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService):

> The life-cycle of this service is managed by Android Wear. This service will be bound to and events delivered as a result of various Android Wear events, including data, messages and events indicating a device has connected or disconnected from the Android Wear network.

This means that the service is only created when Wear has data, messages, etc. to deliver to your app - when there isn't anything to deliver, the service is destroyed and takes up no resources whatsoever.

If you have *any* case where you want to receive callbacks while your process is not already open, then implementing a `WearableListenerService` is exactly what you should be doing.